# CouchDB filtering by date

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

On `Android` using `CouchDB` with `CouchBase Lite` I am trying to replicate a database also I use filter in order to get documents  with a field whose name is `device_number`
So I have this filter:

```
"1": "function(doc, req) {
  if(doc.ismaster || doc._deleted)
return false; 
  if( 1 == doc.device_num || 22 == doc.device_num || 25 == doc.device_num || 41 == doc.device_num )
return true;
  else 
return false;}",
```

It works perfectly and I get all the documents for the devices: 1, 2 , 25 ,41.
Well now I want to get documents for device_num = 22 and 21  and whose creation_date has less than 60 days from the present day so I do:

```
 "1": "function(doc, req) {
      if(doc.ismaster || doc._deleted)
    return false; 
      if( 22 == doc.device_num && 21 == doc.device_num && (Math.ceil((new Date(Date.now()).getTime() - new Date(doc.creation_date.split('/')[2], doc.creation_date.split('/')[1] - 1, doc.creation_date.split('/')[0]).getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) <= 60) )
    return true;
      else 
    return false;}",
```

but I am not getting results,  0 documents, and is not true because in the database there are documents with less than 60 days.

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain your date calculation. And post your code in such a way that we dont have to scroll half an hour.

Comment: So all evaluates to more than 60 days? Did you check? To how many days?

Comment: I evaluate if the document has less than 60 days from the presnt day

Comment: your code is checking 22 twice, unlike your description? My guess is a boolean logic error where you check one value must be both 21 and 22, but storing and parsing locale specific date formats is also a risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get documents for device_num = 22 and 21 and whose
>   creation_date has less than 60 days from the present day

English wording: "I want documents for 21 **and** 22" is actually "I'll accept any document where the document is for either 21 **or** 22":

```
       if( (22 == doc.device_num || 21 == doc.device_num) && ...)
```

as no document with a single device_num can simultaneously be for devices 21 and 22.

Dates are a bit of a mess around the world and who knows if your user's are in the same time zone? Couchdb provides [some examples](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/views/collation.html#sorting-by-dates) of considering collation factors in dates, and here is an example of using `number` type for safe collation:

```
 // creation:
 {tstamp:+new Date(), device_num:22, ...}
 // test
 validstamp = +new Date() - 1000*60*60*24*60;
 if( (22 == doc.device_num || 21 == doc.device_num) && Number(doc.tstamp) > validstamp)
     ...
```

Its nice to use `Number()` in case something went wrong in storage and you have stored a string. But as numbers, they are logically sequential without oddities of non-zero padded strings around the early 1980s and the distant future and you can later refactor to using mango indexes with:

```
{
  "tstamp": {'$gt':validstamp},
  "$or": [
      { "device_num": 21 },
      { "device_num": 22 }
  ]
}
```